# After Dual Boot installation I cant boot to ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

So I created a usb to install the ubuntu, and everything about the installation went perfect but here is the thing, at the end it said to restart my pc and it booted on windows 10. No Grub2 menu, nothing, I just cant boot to ubuntu.

After some restarts, I press the ESC button, then F9 and finally I could see the ubuntu as an option and but in them but I dont like that method. I tried EasyBCD but no luck, re-installed the ubuntu also no luck.

I've also tried legacy bot on/of and secure boot on/off. Is there any way to make the purple grub appear when I power my pc?

Pc info: Windows 10 64bit, Hp pavilion-n211sv, 6GB Ram and some i7

PS: right now I have deleted again that ubuntu partition to try some other usb maker to see if it will help

Comment: Duplicate of [Not showing GRUB in windows 10 dual boot](http://askubuntu.com/questions/828420/not-showing-grub-in-windows-10-dual-boot?rq=1)

Comment: @hamiheim I'll check it if it works

Comment: Be sure to install in UEFI mode if Windows is UEFI. But then you have the HP issue that it violates UEFI standards. Work arounds: Sony, HP & others:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789 and: Boot-Repair should automatically do this with 'use standard EFI file':
http://askubuntu.com/questions/582073/dual-boot-but-only-windows-boots/582114#582114

Comment: See [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/325048/cleaning-up-and-changing-the-efi-boot-order-permanently-using-eifbootmgr) and [this one.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/235567/windows-8-removes-grub-as-default-boot-manager) If EasyUEFI, `bcdedit`, and `easyuefi` don't permanently change your boot order, then your firmware is defective and you must use the file-renaming hack -- or better yet, if possible, return the defective computer to the store and get one that works.

Comment: @oldfred You awesome mate, windows are uefi and I was doing a legacy install!

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that you are installing in the same boot mode. (UEFI/Legacy BIOS).
2. Make sure that Ubuntu is 1st (or above Windows Boot Manager) in boot sequence in firmware settings.

Answer (score 0):

Try running boot repair on the ubuntu live installation.
It should repair grub. Also, try changing to Legacy BIOS if you are using UEFI or the other way around.